# how to solve email not sent error in magento?

Tags: magento2, php, database

> I getting this error

> main.CRITICAL: Unable to send mail: Unknown
> error {"exception":"[object]
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException(code: 0): Unable to send
> mail: Unknown error at
> /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php:103,
> Laminas\Mail\Transport\Exception\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable
> to send mail: Unknown error at
> /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:304)"}

Comment: Are you checking into the local?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes

Comment: @DhirenVasoya how i can solve this error please help me bro

Comment: You can install the SMTP and configured this one, then you can able to do that one.

Comment: okay bro i will check it

Comment: @DhirenVasoya 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
how i can solve this error in SMTP configration

Comment: Which password and username should be entered in the Username and Password fields?

Comment: 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c12sm13612062pfl.56 - gsmtp  getting this type error